# UTF8 strings in Javascript window.open to be intercepted by UIWebview's shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: javascript, objective-c, utf-8, uiwebview

I have a page with JS in my UIWebview which is to send some non-english text to my Obj C code. When I do a NSlog of what I receive in my Obj C code I get garbled output. Can someone see what is wrong here:

JS Code:

```
window.open("http://nothing.com?ST=nǐ",null);
```

Obj C code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

   NSLog([[request URL] absoluteString]);
   return YES;

}
```

Console output:

http://nothing.com?ST=n㽲79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the string as *format* of `NSLog()`. With

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
```

you will get the expected output.

Detailed explanation: The UTF-8 sequence for ǐ is C7 90. The contents of `[[request URL] absoluteString]` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is

> http://nothing.com/?ST=n%C7%90

If you use this as format string, the "%C" will be replaced by a random character.

To get rid of the percent escapes, use

```
NSString *url = [[[request URL] absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Its still not working though ... I am now getting http://nothing.com/?ST=n%C7%90 . So now, the question is, how do I compose a NSString out of its UTF8 hexcode %C7%90

Comment: @Amarsh: I have added that to my answer.